# Button position in accordion

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put BM button on the right most of header section to eliminate one row. Here is my code:

```
<div id="accordion">
  <h3>
      <div>
      <div contenteditable="true">
           <text> f1 </text>|
           <text> bs1 </text>|
           <text> bt1 </text>|
      </div>
      <button type="button">BM</button>
          </div>
    </h3>
  <div>
      <input type="checkbox" name="animal" value="C" checked="true"/>W1 <br />
      <input type="checkbox" name="animal" value="D" />W2<br />
      <input type="checkbox" name="animal" value="B" />w3<br />


  </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nez52khy/

I could also edit the code in the following, however, once I try to edit text, button is also shown in div element.
http://jsfiddle.net/c7xhykmL/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<div id="accordion">
    <h3>
        <div>
            <div contenteditable="true" style="display:inline-block;">
                <text> f1 </text>|
                <text> bs1 </text>|
                <text> bt1 </text>|
            </div>
            <button type="button" style="float:right;">BM</button>
        </div>
    </h3>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="animal" value="C" checked="true"/>W1 <br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="animal" value="D" />W2<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="animal" value="B" />w3<br />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Shall we move button the right most, rather than next to text ?

Comment: @user1724168 edited with style of `float:right;` to the button (its behind the full page link of the snippet) you can see it better if you click "full page" lol